# Command 'sed' didn't work on Solaris

Tags: sed, solaris

I have file 'result.xml'.

> <date>10/19/2011 12:11:05 AM</date>
> <name>Jack</name>

I want to replace date in tag <date>10/19/2011 12:11:05 AM</date> with <date>MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM</date>.

The output file that I want is

> <date>MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM</date>
> <name>Jack</name>

I use command

```
sed '%date% c\<date>MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM<\/generate_date>' result.xml > output.xml
```

and this command is work on Linux but didn't work on Solaris10 that have error message 'sed: command garbled'

I found sed command with 'c\' option didn't work on solaris, could you me advice to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the 's' command of sed?

```
sed 's@<date>.*</date>@<date>MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM</date>@'
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the generally poor state of the solaris UNIX tools (like `sed`), many people compile and install the GNU tools (the ones that most Linux distributions used). I've only seen this from the user side, can't tell you if Sun makes them available.

Answer (score 0):

Old unix seds require more hand holding ;-) ... Try

```
sed '%date% c\
  <date>MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM<\/generate_date>

' result.xml > output.xml
```